# Cordova in Visual Studio dont update Java code when Debug

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a weird issure in Visual Studio 2015 and Apache Cordova 5.4, when I update the javascript code, all works well, but when I update the plugin code writen in Java, the Debug or Release methods, in the emulator and in the device dont update the plugin code correctly, like have a "cache".

I put in the plugin code bad code or change class names, and when I press Debug in device the code continue working like the Java code of the cordova plugins is not recompiled again.

I dont know if I misss something, I try to use Debug/Release, press Rebuild (Solution and other) Clean solution, etc, but the code is the code when I install the plugin not with my modifications after install plugin by the VS IDE.

Im looking in google for similar issures and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the source files in `projectRoot\platforms\android\src\...` instead of just in `projectRoot\plugins\...`.
A plugin JS files can be edited in the `projectRoot\platforms\android\platform_www\plugins\...` directory.

Comment: Yes, it is, but i dont understand, why the www folder are copied every time I compile, and the plugins not?

Comment: Additionally you can add a plugin via CLI as a symlink using `cordova plugin add ..\path\to\plugin --link` so that the changes you made in `platforms\android\src` automatically get back into the local plugin folder (you need to clone it somewhere locally first).